# Is it possible to setup wiki-project on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, wiki

Is there any wiki engine for Google App Engine platform? Or, there are any ports of Mediawiki and other engines for GAE?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can instantiate a ready-to-go MediaWiki image from the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Marketplace.

Please see [this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/browse?q=mediawiki&filter=price:free), where I filtered out only 3 free MediaWiki images but you can check out all other options as well.

Provisioning/setting-up images from GCP Marketplace is very straightforward from my experience - you can have your own Mediawiki server up-and-running in a couple of minutes.

Comment: The question asks for solutions for GAE rather than the more generic GCP.